# SQL Editor of SAP HANA Vora Tools cannot connect with HANA

Tags: sql, bigdata, hana, vora

I try to show SAP HANA tables from SQL Editor of SAP HANA Vora Tools like below:

```
show tables 
using com.sap.spark.hana
options 
(
host "192.168.88.200",
instance "00",
port "30215",
user "SYSTEM",
passwd "Passw0rd",
dbschema "LEAGUE_SCHEMA"
);
```

but appears this error:

> com.sap.spark.hana.client.HANAJdbcBadStateException:
> [DefaultHANAConfiguration(192.168.88.200,00,30215,SYSTEM,Passw0rd,None)]
> Cannot acquire a connection with error code 0, status ERROR_STATUS
>
> [image: ERROR]

Host, instance, port, user, passwd parameters are correct, and the dbschema is created in SAP HANA successfully.

What could be the error?

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the 'port' parameter if it is not a multi-tenant HANA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! omitting the 'port' parameter 
I've been able to show SAP HANA tables!

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified from command line that you are able to ping and reach IP address 192.168.88.200?

Also, typically in HANA the SQL port is 3{InstanceNumber}15.

So in your case if the Instance is in fact 00, then the port should be 30015.

Comment: Thanks for your help! IP address was wrong. Changing the IP and omitting the 'port' parameter i've been able to show SAP HANA tables!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with tenant databases add the `tenantdatabase` parameter:

```
SHOW TABLES USING com.sap.spark.hana
  OPTIONS (
    host "a.b.c.d",
    instance "90",
    user "SYSTEM",
    passwd "password",
    tenantdatabase "SYSTEMDB",
    dbschema "SYSTEM",
    tablepattern "%"
  );
```